# Excel PowerQuery - custom function/query to get cell values from files

Tags: excel, powerquery

Goal: I'm looking to create a sort of index-file that lists all .xlsx-files in the current folder and all sub-folders, including information from specific cells in those .xlsx-files.

Current status: I have a query (From Folder) that gives me a table simply listing .xlsx files in subfolders (along with edit/create dates etc).

Problem:
I want to add columns in the above-mentioned table that reference specific named cells in those files.
I get that I may have to create a blank query with a custom function and then use that in a new column in the first query, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
ValueColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "NamedRangVal", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Folder Path] & [Source.Name])){[Item="YourNamedRange",Kind="DefinedName"]}[Data]{0}[Column1])
```